# How can I install different versions of Rails and keep the existing ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had Rails 2.3.5 installed, and wanted to upgrade to 2.3.10 as a stepping stone to Rails 3. I thought running `gem install rails -v=2.3.10` would install 2.3.10 and keep 2.3.5 as well. But now when I do `rails -v`, it only lists Rails 2.3.10. How can I install different versions of Rails and keep the existing ones?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`gem list rails` should show you all installed versions of Rails. You can specify which one you want each project to use in the `config/environment.rb` file.

Alternately (or "additionally"), look in to [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) (particularly the "gemset" function) for maintaining separate gem sets for each project.

**Updated May 2017** Instead of RVM gemsets, best practice for managing gems in Rails projects (including the Rails gem itself) is to use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/). Bundler's Gemfile will list all the gems your project uses, and allows you to "pin" versions, so by changing the version pin for Rails and running `bundle` you can update your project to the new version.

`<sarcasm>`Now that I've said that, though, Bundler is probably on the way out to be replaced by something else. `</sarcasm>`

Comment: RVM gemsets are the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

You still have both versions, as the other answers have mentioned.  However, you don't want to call `rails newapp` and then change the config/environment.rb file.  This will cause problems for any files that have changed between versions.  Instead, create a new 2.3.5 app this way:

```
rails _2.3.5_ newapp
```

And you'll run the exact version of rails you want, to create the file structure correctly.  I don't know why this isn't documented better.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you can install many versions of the rails gem without conflict. However, each project is created using a specific version. To install a new version of the rails gem as follow;
Change the version 3.2.18 with any version you like (see link below for all available versions).

```
gem install rails --version=3.2.18
```

To install the latest version

```
gem install rails
```

To check all the rails version available, check out this link

[Here is a link to all the version of rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions)

You might consider updating your gem software by this command prior to loading new gems.

```
gem update --system
```

As per @pjmorse, list the version installed with this command

```
gem list rails
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can define the Rails version of an application in `config/enviroment.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

You can vendor the version of rails you want into your vendor/rails folder. At the command line just run rake `rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.2'. You don't need any version of rails installed for this to work it will take the source and build it from the remote source in your vendor directory.

```
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.1
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.2
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.3
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.4
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.5
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.6
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.7
rake rails:freeze:edge RELEASE=2.2.8
```